# My VGG16 Model's training and validation accuracy scores are stuck

Tags: image-classification, vgg16

Im trying to create an image classification model that classifies plants from an image dataset made up of 33 classes, the total amount of images is 41,808, the images are unbalanced but that is something me and my thesis team will work on using Kfold; but going back to the main problem.

The VGG16 model itself is from a pre-trained model from keras

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

base_model = keras.applications.VGG16(
   include_top=True,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=None,
    pooling=None,
    classes=1000,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255.0,
    fill_mode='nearest'

)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/content/DatabaseExpandedV1',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/content/DatabaseExpandedV1',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

model = keras.Sequential([
    base_model,
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(33, activation='softmax')
])

optimizerSGD = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD (learning_rate=0.001, momentum = 0.01)
optimizerAdam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(
    optimizer= optimizerSGD,
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=len(validation_generator)
)
```

this is the result of one of the initial testings I have done with it:
[image]

what I have done so far is changing the optimizers from SGD to Adam, but the results are generally the same.

Am I doing something wrong or is there anything I can do to improve on this model to get it to atleast be in a "working" state, regardless if its overfitting or the like as that can be fixed later.

This is also the link to our dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/134CTAf3KNFrm9Lm2IUWQn1GjCG1UeD_s/view?usp=sharing
It is specifically a dataset consisting of Medicinal Plants and Herbs in our region with their augmentations. The are not yet resized and normalized in the dataset.